Regex match exact item in Google sheets
I'm trying to use the regexmatch function in Google Sheets to match the item "hip hop" in the bolded cases in the lists below:
- atl hip hop, dirty south rap, hip hop, pop rap
- hip hop, dirty south rap, pop rap
so what I'm after is basically standalone hip hop in between commas (or at the beginning or end of string) - without any prefix or postfix.
Here's my formula but its not matching correct:
=REGEXMATCH(LIST,"(\\W|^)(,\\ship\\shop,)(\\W|$)") 


Sigh. What does it match? Descriptive errors please.

non-regex alternative: =isnumber(search(", hip hop,",", "&A1&","))

I hate these kind of complex regex, I'd split on comma, then remove whitespace from start and end and then finally match against "hip hop"... Just a thought.

You need to use
=REGEXMATCH(LIST,"^(?:.*,\s*)?hip\shop(?:\s*,.*)?$") 

See the regex demo.
Note the ^ and $ anchors are only present for ease of debugging on external sites, since REGEXMATCH requires a full string match anyway.
Details

^ - start of string
(?:.*,\s*)? - an optional occurrence of

.* - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
, - a comma
\s* - zero or more whitespaces


hip\shop - hip, a whitespace, hop
(?:\s*,.*)? - an optional occurrence of zero or more whitespaces, a comma and any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
$ - end of string.


thanks, this works great! also, I don't know if you saw my previous comments. they've somehow been deleted. but thanks for the step-by-step explanation.
